# Cons an Iterable

Tags: java, collections, guava

I cannot find a method cons.  Such a method would add a single item to an Iterable.  Instead, do I have to use

```
Iterables.concat(list, Collections.singletonList(item))
```

?  The following would be quite nice.

```
Iterables.cons(list, item)
```

Comment: You should make a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/entry) if you want this (though it may well not be added).

Comment: A `cons` function in the Lisp sense would add the single item in front, not at the end.

Comment: If you have a list, why are you using iterables? Why not just `list.add(item)`?

Comment: Or if you want it in the front; `list.add(0, item)`. Perhaps off-topic, but if it's not a `List`, why call it that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, write a method `cons(Iterable<T>, T)` that makes the slightly-more complicated call to `concat`.